# Microsoft Access Fixes not Propagating/Errors Not Reproducible In Dev Environment

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

OK so this is kind of a general question here. We run an ASP/C# Site that's fed by a SQL 2008 R2 database.

Our data entry takes place using Microsoft Access 2007 and feeds to a SQL 2008 R2 instance.

Our data entry forms (all .adp) are generally simple, but we randomly run into problems where I'll post a change to the DB (we have a script that runs at night and will archive our old DB versions in the form of "DB_NAME.adp03122012" and keeps the newest revision as "DB_NAME.adp". This way, our data entry team will just need to click on a network shortcut to access the Access forms.

What we're running into is non-reproducible errors of varying types on random machines.

Example, I make a simple search that has a combo box and a search button. You select the item you want to search for and it updates the record source to search for that PK/FK. It works fine on my developer box. It works fine on certain end-user boxes. But on others, it throws a run-time error:

> "Run-time error 2467: The expression you entered refers to an object
>   that is closed or doesn't exist".

Now the error itself isn't the focus of this. It's not being able to reproduce it. I tried running it on another box that has the same hardware specs as the offending box and it ran fine, no errors, no nothing.

I'm at an absolute loss as to why this is happening. I don't think the error is actually related to my VB code or to our databases, as it's working fine on some computers and isn't working on others. It's almost as if the code isn't propagating properly to specific boxes.

Has anybody else dealt with this before?

Comment: Are all the necessary references (.ocx's, .dll's, etc) in place on the offending machines?

Comment: It might help to look at the references for MISSING, if you have not already done so.

Comment: @mwolfe02 I can only assume so. I'm honestly not sure how to check for these things.

Comment: @Remou I'm not sure how to check on these things. I apologize for not knowing more about the system before submitting questions; we've all just been kind of thrown into the deep end as far as Access development goes.

Comment: That all said, I'm googling how to do these things.

Comment: From the code window (Alt+F11), choose Tools->References. If a reference is missing, it will be clearly marked MISSING.

Comment: OK, I did exactly that: checked the references from where you told me. There weren't any missing. I did notice that the ActiveX Data Objects Library was different than a working machine, but swapping out those libraries didn't do anything.

Comment: And your code compiles on the "bad" machine?

Comment: The code does indeed compile on the "bad" machines. All I can think to do is manually take the VBA text on that particular form module and literally email it to the party with the "bad" machine and ensure that the code is copying over correctly.

I sincerely appreciate you following up with this issue. I am leaving for the day from my office (doctor's appointment), but I'll be trying whatever comes next in the morning.

Comment: Please post the line that is highlighted when the code fails.

Comment: Just to clarify Remou's comment about checking for MISSING references: you would need to do that on the "bad" machines.  Which would require a full version of Access installed on those machines and not just the run-time.

Comment: Thank you both for following up with me.

After beating my head against the wall trying everything else that would stick, it turns out a nice run-in with Windows Update solved the issue - or so it would seem. That's pretty embarrassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel somewhat foolish, but our Network Admin hadn't propagated Windows updates to all of our end user boxes.

The advice that Remou and mwolfe02 gave was valid and helpful, and likely would've helped had I been informed that the computers in question needed updates.

Thank you for reading and offering comments and help.